# How do you know how many nephalem valor stacks you have? Is it shown somewhere?

Tags: diablo-iii

How do you know how many nephalem valor stacks you have? Is it 
shown somewhere?

Answer (score 9):

The stacks show up as a buff on your buff bar. The number in the bottom right corner shows how many stacks you have.

[image: NV Stacks]

Comment: came here to say the same. Take my upvote :)

Comment: Btw this screenshot is old as you get stacks for completing events and opening the big golden chests I currently don't know the name of.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Resplendent Chests.

Comment: Nephalem Valor are only obtainable once you reached level 60.